# Logical operators in a Data.Frame in R

Tags: r, logical-operators

This is mydataframe:

```
    x<-structure(list(ABEV3 = c(1, -0.0329694340790399, -0.600795689797522, 
-0.300219759273298), AZUL4 = c(-0.0329694340790399, 1, 0.531987810491871, 
0.884036954118666), BTOW3 = c(-0.600795689797522, 0.531987810491871, 
1, 0.612824308045668), B3SA3 = c(-0.300219759273298, 0.884036954118666, 
0.612824308045668, 1)), row.names = c("ABEV3", "AZUL4", "BTOW3", 
"B3SA3"), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to remove all the values that match this criteria: if x[i,j] is bigger than 0.85 and lower than 0.99 it stays in my dataframe (PRESERVING de row and column name):

So I did this:

```
y<- x>0.35 & x<0.99
```

But when I run: `x[y]` it is not a dataframe. And its not preserving the column/row names.

How can I correct this using the same steps? I.e, using the logical matrix y ?

My final output should be this one:

```
out<-structure(c(0.5319878, 0.884037, 0.53198781, 0.88403695, 0.6128243, 
0.5319878), .Dim = 3:2, .Dimnames = list(c("AZUL4", "BTOW3", 
"B3SA3"), c("BTOW3", "B3SA3")))
```

PS: The idea is simply remove from my x data.frame the values that do not match with the `x>0.85 & x<0.99` criteria.

Comment: `y` is a matrix as big as your frame. When you say "remove all the values", do you mean *"replace them what `NA`"*, or something that cannot be done in R *"make those cells in the frame completely empty"*. (Technically you can convert all columns into list-columns so that `NULL` is allowed, but it breaks a lot of things and is otherwise difficult to work with.)

Comment: It would be useful to know what your expected output is. **Edit**: try `x[!y] <- NA`.

Comment: Guys, I will edit the qestion.

Comment: Maybe the following would work for you? x[y] <- NA

Comment: @Enrique this is the idea! But the NA values is exactly what I want to fit the criteria. The other values should be NA. Right?

Comment: @Laura then: x[!y] <- NA

Comment: @Enrique Yes! Thanks!

Comment: You wanted a base solution, got a one-liner in comments and in an answer, and then accepted the non-base solution? Odd, \*shrug\*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach using `dplyr`...

```r
x <- x %>% mutate(r=rownames(.)) %>% gather(k,v,-r,factor_key = T) %>% 
  filter(v>0.85 & v<0.99) %>% spread(k,v)
rownames(x) <- x$r
x <- x %>% select(-r)
x

          AZUL4     B3SA3     BRSR6     BBSE3     BRML3     BBDC3     BBDC4
AZUL4        NA 0.8840370 0.8608257 0.8861292        NA 0.9185312 0.8885266
B3SA3 0.8840370        NA 0.9109177 0.9144024        NA 0.9193643 0.9450005
BBDC3 0.9185312 0.9193643 0.9171293 0.9163145 0.9043771        NA 0.9844133
BBDC4 0.8885266 0.9450005 0.9571348 0.8981849 0.8848416 0.9844133        NA
BBSE3 0.8861292 0.9144024        NA        NA 0.8980725 0.9163145 0.8981849
BRML3        NA        NA        NA 0.8980725        NA 0.9043771 0.8848416
BRSR6 0.8608257 0.9109177        NA        NA        NA 0.9171293 0.9571348
```

Does this give the desired output? It will remove columns/rows that have no values that meet the condition, ie, ABEV3 is removed completely and not returned.

Comment: I believe so. But my intention is to use the match between the y matrix and x dataframe. And keep using the base package of R.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just remove values without removing entire row or column. I think you want this -

```
x[x > 0.85 & x < 0.99] <- NA_real_

            ABEV3       AZUL4       BTOW3      B3SA3      BRSR6      BBSE3        BRML3      BBDC3      BBDC4        BRAP4
ABEV3  1.00000000 -0.03296943 -0.60079569 -0.3002198 -0.3971484 -0.1111854 -0.201374719 -0.1459591 -0.2943246 -0.048831117
AZUL4 -0.03296943  1.00000000  0.53198781         NA         NA         NA  0.830385751         NA         NA  0.214403356
BTOW3 -0.60079569  0.53198781  1.00000000  0.6128243  0.8196140  0.4432318  0.560694380  0.6530405  0.7307261  0.064940995
B3SA3 -0.30021976          NA  0.61282431  1.0000000         NA         NA  0.820488340         NA         NA  0.184650344
BRSR6 -0.39714843          NA  0.81961398         NA  1.0000000  0.7963561  0.781602231         NA         NA  0.140952812
BBSE3 -0.11118541          NA  0.44323184         NA  0.7963561  1.0000000           NA         NA         NA  0.136343833
BRML3 -0.20137472  0.83038575  0.56069438  0.8204883  0.7816022         NA  1.000000000         NA         NA  0.009409914
BBDC3 -0.14595908          NA  0.65304052         NA         NA         NA           NA  1.0000000         NA  0.116203752
BBDC4 -0.29432460          NA  0.73072606         NA         NA         NA           NA         NA  1.0000000  0.126570544
BRAP4 -0.04883112  0.21440336  0.06494099  0.1846503  0.1409528  0.1363438  0.009409914  0.1162038  0.1265705  1.000000000
```

Comment: now how can I have a "clean" data.frame removing the NA values?

Comment: @Laura what do you mean by removing `NA` values? You'd have to remove entire rows or columns containing `NA`.

Comment: the position [4,2] it is not interesting for me. I would like to remove. And then I would have a small data.frame.

Comment: @Laura In that case you'd have to entirely remove either row 4 or column 2. Can't just remove a single value. You can always ignore `NA` in your analysis if that's what you want.